# How I can get the time, where I am in a map for osu?

Tags: c#

How I can get the time, where I am in a map for osu???

I need an **osu!api** solution, and I want to get this value:

0:05.12

or something like this.

Comment: Have you looked at the [wiki](https://github.com/ppy/osu-api/wiki) yet? If it's not there then it probably doesn't exist.